# Generate swagger/openapi docs from Mocha/Chai test suite

Tags: node.js, tdd, swagger, openapi

I want to use [Swagger/OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) to standardize documentation efforts. Most of the API's are built with NodeJS and I do integration testing with Mocha & Chai which helps tremendously with quickly making sure the API isn't broken after making changes. From what I understand, using Swagger won't replace my integration test but will make it easy for developers to know how to consume my API. If I can tie my documentation efforts into my test suite, it would make on-going documentation maintenance easier. When i add or modify test, I could update API documents in the same place.

What I was thinking about doing is using [YUIDoc](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc) or [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html) which generates API documentation from comments in source. But neither conform to OpenAPI spec. Then I found [Swagger-JSdoc](https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc) and figured I could just put all the comments in my test suite code since I'm already there specifying what to test in the endpoints.

Is there another way/workflow that might be more efficient for new or existing projects? How can I bring my documentation efforts closer to my test suite to improve on-going documentation maintenance?

Comment: You can't generate a specification from tests, but you can generate tests from a specification. You could try something like https://github.com/earldouglas/swagger-test out of the box or rewrite it to testing environment of your choice, i.e. Mocha.

Answer (score 0):

I just published an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-swagger) for the same. Not sure if you found an alternative, if not please feel free to give it a try.
https://github.com/LmntrX/mocha-swagger/

Install [mocha-swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-swagger) *globally* with

```
npm install -g mocha-swagger
```

Then execute the following command:

```
mocha-swagger path/to/project/tests
```

This command will recursively parse test files in your test directory and generate a basic *swagger.json* file in current directory.

NB: Please note that the swagger spec generated will only contain your routes, methods and path parameters.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)